# How to generate a different HTML format from a Nokogiri collection in Ruby

Tags: html, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I'm working on a script that migrates a current HTML page and transforms it into a different HTML layout. I can get the information from the document using Nokogiri and XPath.

The problem is how to traverse the nodes retrieved with a loop in a similar fashion to how an array and a hash are traversed to generate the layout that I need.

This is a sample of the original layout that I am trying to convert:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="somelink1.html">Link 1</a> </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="sublink1.html">Sublink 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="sublink2.html">Sublink 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This code is what I have tried so far. The problem is when it loops through the collection set it outputs all of the nodes in the new HTML tag each time a pass is made through the collection, rather than only outputting information at the current index.

```
require 'nokogiri'
source_file = Nokogiri.XML(open("navigation.inc"))
source_file = Nokogiri.XML(source_file.to_s.encode('UTF-8', 'binary', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: ''))

navigation = ""

if source_file.xpath("//ul[@id = 'nav']").length > 0

   navcontain = source_file.xpath("//ul[@id = 'nav']/li")

   navcontain.each do | child |

   if child.xpath("//li and count(*) = 2")
        navigation = navigation + "<details>"
        child.xpath("//li/ul").each do | children |
                 navigation = navigation + child.xpath("//li/a").to_s

         end #end child loop
        navigation = navigation + "</details>"
     else
        navigation = navigation + source_file.xpath("//ul[@id = 'nav']/li/a").to_s

     end #end conditional check
   end #end initial loop
end #end length check

puts navigation
```

This is an example of what the code above is currently doing:

```
<div id="nav">
    <details>
        <a href="somelink1.html">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="sublink1.html">Sublink 1</a>
        <a href="sublink2.html">Sublink 2</a>
    </details>
    <details>
        <a href="somelink1.html">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="sublink1.html">Sublink 1</a>
        <a href="sublink2.html">Sublink 2</a>
    </details>

</div>
```

The format that I want after the transformation is:

```
<div id="nav">
    <a href="somelink1.html">Link 1</a>

    <details>
        <summary>
            Link 2
        </summary>

        <a href="sublink1.html">Sublink 1</a>
        <a href="sublink2.html">Sublink 2</a>

    </details>

</div>
```

I believe part of the code works correctly as I can identify the total number of single and second-level link structures. I haven't figured out how to translate the data to the final version I need.

Comment: This is a perfect use case for XSLT...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted doesn't produce the output you posted. The code actually produces this:

```
<a href="somelink1.html">Link 1</a>
<a href="#">Link 2</a>
<details>
  <a href="somelink1.html">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="sublink1.html">Sublink 1</a>
  <a href="sublink2.html">Sublink 2</a>
</details>
```

I guess you don't want `Link 1` and `Link 2` in the `<details>` section.

There's a problem with how you are using XPath selectors:

```
child.xpath("//li/ul")
```

searches starting at the root of the document, not at the `child` element. Instead you need to use:

```
child.xpath(".//li/ul")
```

if you want to search starting at the `child` element.

Here's the cleaned up code that should produce the output you need:

```
require 'nokogiri'
source_file = Nokogiri.XML(File.read("navigation.inc").encode('UTF-8', 'binary', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: ''))

navigation = ""

if source_file.xpath("//ul[@id = 'nav']").length > 0
  navcontain = source_file.xpath("//ul[@id = 'nav']/li")

  navcontain.each do |child|
    if child.xpath(".//li and count(*) = 2")
      navigation += "<details>"

      child.xpath(".//ul/li/a").each do |grandchild|
        navigation += grandchild.to_s
      end

      navigation = navigation + "</details>"
    else
      # not sure how that's supposed to work based on your input file example
       navigation = navigation + source_file.xpath("//ul[@id = 'nav']/li/a").to_s
    end
  end
end

puts navigation
```

Comment: See "[What happens if you answered a question, questioner says thanks, but didn't accept your answer as correct?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109773/what-happens-if-you-answered-a-question-questioner-says-thanks-but-didnt-acce)" and "[Do you feel dirty if you nudge new users to accept your answer when they indicate you've answered their question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14994/do-you-feel-dirty-if-you-nudge-new-users-to-accept-your-answer-when-they-indicat)"